# Which methods are changed in migrating wicket from 1.3.6 to 1.4.0?

Tags: wicket

I'm migrating wicket from 1.3.6 to 1.4.0. I get syntax error by getModel() and getModelObject() methods. It says they are undefined, so they prevent application from compiling. Which methods should I use instead of them?

This is part of my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public BreadCrumbTrail(String id, IModel model) {
    super(id, model);

    // Keep a count of the crumbs
    int count = 1;
    // Get the crumbs
    List<Crumb> crumbs = (List<Crumb>) getModelObject();
    // Create a repeating view to render the crumbs within
    RepeatingView repeating = new RepeatingView("crumbs");
    add(repeating);

    // Add each crumb
    for (final Crumb crumb : crumbs) {
        WebMarkupContainer item = new WebMarkupContainer(repeating
                .newChildId());
        repeating.add(item);

        // Create a link from the page held in the crumb
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        Link link = new Link("link", item.getModel()) {
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(crumb.getPage());

            }
        };
        // Add a title/label to the link
        link.add(new Label("title", crumb.getTitle()));
        item.add(link);

        // Is this the last crumb?
        if (count == crumbs.size()) {
            // Don't add the normal separator
            item.add(new Label("separator", " "));
            // Disable the link as this is the current page
            link.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            // Add the separator
            item.add(new Label("separator", " > "));
        }

        // Up the count of crumbs
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone upgrade to 1.4.[0] ?! Why not 1.4.19 which is the latest stable in 1.4.x branch at the moment ?!

Comment: This question shows no research effort at all. Googling 'wicket 1.4 getModelObject' gives the Migration guide as first result, and the first section in it is 'Component.getModel() and friends renamed to getDefaultModel() and friends'. Writing this question took you much longer than actually searching for the solution.

Comment: I did it before asking the question, But I got an exception which was related to something else that I didn't know! I guessed that I'm not in the right track! that's the reason I asked!

Comment: I chose 1.4.0 just because it's the first version in 4.

Comment: @NoushinKhaki I suggest fixing the obvious compilation errors and then asking about exceptions you get instead.

Comment: There was just compilation error which was solved by the ansnwer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `getDefaultModelObject()` instead

Wicket usually provides a migration guide:
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migrating-to-wicket-14.html#MigratingtoWicket1.4-Component.getModel%2528%2529andfriendsrenamedtogetDefaultModel%2528%2529andfriends

BTW: wicket 1.5 is also already out

Comment: for both methods? I mean getModel() and getModelObject()?